# Issue w/ Cascading Combo Boxes deleting field values from records they pull from for Form

Tags: ms-access

My apologies if this question has been answered before but I've searched all day today and haven't been able to find the answer I seek. I'm building a database for requesters to submit requests to order paint using combo boxes that pull from a PaintCatalog table, broken down by ProductName, ProductColor, Nomenclature, UI, StockNumber, DuplFieldCd (I use this a unique key for paints with the same product name but come in multiple colors and Units of Issue.) I've been trying to set up a form to pull the data into cascading combo boxes from this PaintCatalog, with each selection reducing the dropdown choices until it reaches only 1 choice, at which point it autofills specific fields. Then the user clicks a command button and the values in the form fields are used to create a new record in the PaintRequests table. I've got most of that to work, however when I delete values from form's combo box fields when I'm retesting the form, one of the records in the PaintCatalog starts to get blank values. I need this issue fixed before I can progress any further. I've tried using a query instead of referencing the table directly, but the data is still getting edit, deleted, or overwritten. I'm getting that pencil icon every time I'm using one of the form combo box fields. Please advise.

Comment: Is form RecordSource a query that joins tables? Probably have combobox bound to wrong field. Bind form to table and see what happens.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  It would help to have a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Without a minimum reporducible example I can't give you an answer, but do these things.  Never manually delete items from the cascading combo boxes.  It sounds like some of your combo boxes have editable lists when they should be bound to tables, for example:  https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html  next work around this issue for now by setting up the default way to edit paint requests including delete.  select the PaintRequests Table.  hit create form.  Study the default C.R.U.D form especially how to handle deletes. Think about how improve the user experienc